# PoA network with half million blocks, sealers stopped

Tags: go-ethereum

**System information**

```
Geth
Version: 1.8.17-stable
Git Commit: 8bbe72075e4e16442c4e28d999edee12e294329e
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.10.1
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.10
```

**Expected behaviour**

Keep the normal signing.

**Actual behaviour**

I was running a go-ethereum private network with 6 sealers.

Each sealer is run by:

```
directory=/home/poa
command=/bin/bash -c 'geth --datadir sealer4/  --syncmode 'full' --port 30393 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8600 --rpcapi='net,web3,eth' --networkid 30 --gasprice '1' -unlock 'someaddress' --password sealer4/password.txt --mine'
```

The blockchain was running good for about 1-2 months.

Today I found that all the nodes were having issues. Each node was emitting the message "Signed recently, must wait for others"

I check out the logs and i found this message every 1 hour, no more information, the nodes where not mining:

```
Regenerated local transaction journal transactions=0 accounts=0
Regenerated local transaction journal transactions=0 accounts=0
Regenerated local transaction journal transactions=0 accounts=0
Regenerated local transaction journal transactions=0 accounts=0
```

Experimenting the same issue with 6 sealers, I restarted each node but now I'm getting stuck in

```
INFO [01-07|18:17:30.645] Etherbase automatically configured       address=0x5Bc69DC4dba04b6955aC94BbdF129C3ce2d20D34
INFO [01-07|18:17:30.645] Commit new mining work                   number=488677 sealhash=a506ec…8cb403 uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=133.76µs
INFO [01-07|18:17:30.645] Signed recently, must wait for others
```

It's weird that some nodes are stuck on the 488677 and others are on 488676. This behaviour was reported on this issue https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16406, same for the user @lyhbarry

Example:
Signer 1

[image]

Signer 2

[image]

**Note that there is no votes pending**

So, right now, I shut down and restart each node, i have found that:

- Each node is paired with the others
- Each node is part of clique.getSigners()
- Each node is waiting for another to sign...

  INFO [01-07|18:41:56.134] Signed recently, must wait for others 
  INFO [01-07|19:41:42.125] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
  INFO [01-07|18:41:56.134] Signed recently, must wait for others

**So, the synchronization fails but I also can't just start signing again because each node is stuck waiting for the others, that means the network is useless?**

The comment of @tudyzhb on that issue mention that:

> Ref clique-seal of v1.8.11, I think there is no an effective mechanism to retry seal, when an in-turn/out-of-turn seal fail occur. So our dev network useless easily.

After this problem, i take a look at the logs, each signer has this error messages:

```
Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=7875a002affc775b err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
```

```
INFO [01-02|16:42:10.902] Signed recently, must wait for others 
WARN [01-02|16:42:11.960] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=7875a002affc775b err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
INFO [01-02|16:42:12.128] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=540.282µs mgasps=0.000  number=488116 hash=269920…afd3c7 cache=5.99kB
INFO [01-02|16:42:12.129] Commit new mining work                   number=488117 sealhash=f7b00c…787d5c uncles=2 txs=0 gas=0     fees=0          elapsed=307.314µs
INFO [01-02|16:42:20.929] Successfully sealed new block            number=488117 sealhash=f7b00c…787d5c hash=f17438…93ffe3 elapsed=8.800s
INFO [01-02|16:42:20.929]  mined potential block                  number=488117 hash=f17438…93ffe3
INFO [01-02|16:42:20.930] Commit new mining work                   number=488118 sealhash=b09b33…1526ba uncles=2 txs=0 gas=0     fees=0          elapsed=520.754µs
INFO [01-02|16:42:20.930] Signed recently, must wait for others 
INFO [01-02|16:42:31.679] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=2.253ms   mgasps=0.000  number=488118 hash=763a32…a579f5 cache=5.99kB
INFO [01-02|16:42:31.680]  block reached canonical chain          number=488111 hash=3d44dc…df0be5
INFO [01-02|16:42:31.680] Commit new mining work                   number=488119 sealhash=c8a5e7…db78a1 uncles=2 txs=0 gas=0     fees=0          elapsed=214.155µs
INFO [01-02|16:42:31.680] Signed recently, must wait for others 
INFO [01-02|16:42:40.901] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=808.903µs mgasps=0.000  number=488119 hash=accc3f…44bc4c cache=5.99kB
INFO [01-02|16:42:40.901] Commit new mining work                   number=488120 sealhash=f73978…c03fa7 uncles=2 txs=0 gas=0     fees=0          elapsed=275.72µs
INFO [01-02|16:42:40.901] Signed recently, must wait for others 
WARN [01-02|16:42:41.961] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=7875a002affc775b err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
```

I also see some:

```
INFO [01-02|16:58:10.902]  block lost                             number=488205 hash=1fb1c5…a41a42
```

This error about hash chain was just a warning, so the node keeps mining until the 2nd of January, then I saw this **on each of the 6 nodes**

[image]

I was looking that there are a lot of issues about this error, the most similar is the one I posted here but is unresolved.

Most of the issues' workarounds seems to be a restart, but in this case, the chain seems to be in a inconsistent state and the nodes are always waiting for the others.

So,

1. Any ideas?
2. Any logs that I can provide? I only see the warnings of the error described and the block lost, but nothing when the node stoped to be mining
3. Is this PR related? https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/18072
4. Could it be related to the comment of @karalabe on this issue https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16406?
5. Will upgrading from 1.8.17 to 1.8.20 solve this?
6. In my opinion, it seems like a race condition or something, since I have 2 chains, one running for 2 months, the other one for three months and this is the first time this error happens

Github discussion:

github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/18402

This is the other related issue:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16444 (Same issue but I don't have votes pending in my snapshot)

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14381#

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16825

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16406

Comment: You might wanna point to this issue with has even more information https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/18402

Comment: I created that issue haha, i will add it, thanks!!